# How to demonstrate a real time example of using BeforeTest, AfterTest, BeforeSuite, AfterSuite, BeforeClass, AfterClass annotations in TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng, testng-eclipse, testng-annotation-test

How to demonstrate real time example of using `BeforeTest`, `AfterTest`, `BeforeSuite`, `AfterSuite`, `BeforeClass`, `AfterClass`, `BeforeMethod`, `AfterMethod` annotations in TestNG Selenium.

Comment: Please follow the documentation from testNG: https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! 
You'd need to review the documentation from testNG to learn how to use this functionality, Stack overflow is a site for asking and answering questions around specific problems you're having, which need workable examples and code provided with a clear view of your specific issue and desired outcome.

What you're asking for is a broad overview of functionality, which isn't what this site is for. Please review:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it
and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For demonstrating a real time example of using `BeforeTest`, `AfterTest`, `BeforeSuite`, `AfterSuite`, `BeforeClass`, `AfterClass` *annotations* through [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) you don't need Selenium.

Once you install the *TestNG* plugin within your *IDE* you simply need to:

- Mention the annotations for the methods. Example:

  - `@BeforeSuite`
  - `@BeforeClass`
  - `@BeforeMethod`
  - `@BeforeTest`
  - `@Test`
  - `@AfterTest`
  - `@AfterMethod`
  - `@AfterClass`
  - `@AfterSuite`
- Add the relevant imports for the classes.

  - `import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;`
  - `import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;`
  - `import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;`
  - `import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;`
  - `import org.testng.annotations.Test;`
  - `import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;`
  - `import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;`
  - `import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;`
  - `import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;`
- Sample Code Block:

  ```
  package demo;

  import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
  import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
  import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
  import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  public class TestNG_Annotation_Demo {

      @BeforeSuite
      public void before_suite()
      {
          System.out.println("I am in BeforeSuite");
      }

      @BeforeClass
      public void before_class()
      {
          System.out.println("I am in BeforeClass");
      }

      @BeforeMethod
      public void before_method()
      {
          System.out.println("I am in BeforeMethod");
      }

      @BeforeTest
      public void before_test()
      {
          System.out.println("I am in BeforeTest");
      }

      @Test
      public void test()
      {
          System.out.println("I am in Test");
      }

      @AfterTest
      public void after_test()
      {
          System.out.println("I am in AfterTest");
      }

      @AfterMethod
      public void after_method()
      {
          System.out.println("I am in AfterMethod");
      }

      @AfterClass
      public void after_class()
      {
          System.out.println("I am in AfterClass");
      }

      @AfterSuite
      public void after_suite()
      {
          System.out.println("I am in AfterSuite");
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
  I am in BeforeSuite
  I am in BeforeTest
  I am in BeforeClass
  I am in BeforeMethod
  I am in Test
  I am in AfterMethod
  I am in AfterClass
  I am in AfterTest
  PASSED: test

  ===============================================
      Default test
      Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================

  I am in AfterSuite

  ===============================================
  Default suite
  Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================
  ```